# How to check if object is an instance of Express.Router?

Tags: node.js, express, type-assertion

Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly?

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import assert from 'assert'

let routerInstance = new Router();

assert(routerInstance instanceof Router); // this is throwing an error
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little experiment, I did this instead:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(routerInstance) == express.Router; //this returns true
```